# Bandwidth monitoring in Linux

Tags: networking, command-line, monitoring

I just need to get how much bandwidth is used in 3 or 4 days. Do you have any application in the terminal to do it?

I'd prefer if it didn't use SNMP.

I found `iptraf`, `wireshark`, `cacti`, but they were not what I am looking for.

Of course I need to save my results; for a single computer, not a network.

It's very important that I can see the total size of inbound and outboud traffic. 
What solutions are there for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know you already have that with `ifconfig` right?

Ifconfig keeps counters about your incomming and outgoing bandwidth on each interface by default. Usually you can't reset counters except rebooting ([with a few exceptions](http://www.ducea.com/2006/09/08/resetting-ifconfig-counters/))

From console you can easily leave a cron running each three days and saving results to a file for later check.
Something like this:

```
date >> ~/bw.log && ifconfig eth0|grep byte >> ~/bw.log
```

Will produce this kind of output per run on the file bw.log at users home.

```
Thu Oct 18 03:44:05 UTC 2012
      RX bytes:414910161 (395.6 MiB)  TX bytes:68632105 (65.4 MiB)
```

My two cents...

Comment: Is it possible to reset this counter without breaking network connectivity?

Comment: @l0b0 It will always break, as when you restart networking configuration. However, if done right it will mean no more than a couple of seconds without connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

`vnstat` can log how many bytes have been transferred for an interface, but not application based, you can only know the bytes as a whole.